# Neo4j Rest Cypher Qyery to match node : Errors

Tags: rest, cypher

I am sending cypher query using REST API as shown below:

```
MATCH (user:Profile)-[:HAS_SEARCHED]-(term{name:"TV"}) 
WITH [x in collect(user)| id(x) ] AS userIDs 
MATCH(user:Profile) where id(user) in userIDs 
MATCH (user)-[r:HAS_SEARCHED]->(term:SearchTerm) 
return term.name
```

Although the query executes well when running on the server directly, gives below error in eclipse:

```
{"results":[],"errors":[{"code":"Neo.ClientError.Request.InvalidFormat",
"message":"Unable to deserialize request: 
Unexpected character ('T' (code 84)): was expecting comma to separate OBJECT entries\n at 
[Source: HttpInputOverHTTP@2543f0f2; line: 1, column: 85]"}]}
```

Please help!! Thanks

Comment: How do you use the *Using Cypher REST API* ?

Comment: Sounds as if the JSON you're sending to the server is not correct, can you validate it with a JSON validator?

Comment: Sorry for the misformed query.Edited the question language above.Thanks

Comment: Yeah , I was I shouldn't have passed the parameters like above. Below json works well.POST [{"statements" : [ {"statement" : "MATCH (user:Profile)-[:HAS_SEARCHED]-(term{name:{name}}) WITH distinct user MATCH (user)-[r:HAS_SEARCHED]->(term:SearchTerm) return term.name" , "parameters": { "name": "TV"}} ]}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your query, you don't need to match the users twice:

```
MATCH (user:Profile)-[:HAS_SEARCHED]-(term:SearchTerm {name:"TV"}) 
WITH distinct user
MATCH (user)-[r:HAS_SEARCHED]->(term:SearchTerm) 
RETURN term.name, count(*) as freq
```

or even:

```
MATCH (term:SearchTerm {name:"TV"})<-[:HAS_SEARCHED]-(:Profile)-[:HAS_SEARCHED]->(term:SearchTerm) 
RETURN term.name, count(*) as freq
```